# Creating multiple Scenes with CLASS and calling them(classes)

Tags: java, javafx

I was assigned in school to build a small JAVAFX program with buttons that travels through different Scenes (layouts).

My program is a log in window, and details window. But I have to create the details window in a different class than Main class. How do I make the button call the 'details window'from Main when it's a class?

(See createAccountBtn.setOnAction)

[Main Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzK4l.png)

[Detail window Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4z9L.png)

So Here's the deal: I created an interface where I put this method:

```
 void displayLayout(VBox layout);
```

And then It triggers this method in Main:

```
public void displayLayout(VBox layout){
    Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 200, 200);
    window.setScene(scene);
```

I also have in Main this:

```
   Button createAccountBtn = new Button("Create new account");
    createAccountBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

           displayLayout(new DetailScreen(listener));

        }
    });
     layout = new VBox();
    layout.getChildren().addAll(accountNumberTF, loginBtn, createAccountBtn);
    layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    displayLayout(layout);
    window.show();
```

Which is the layout options and the button. the setOnAction button points to a new Class that inherits VBox and acts as a layout:

```
private ChangeScreenListener listener;

    public DetailScreen(ChangeScreenListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;

        Button exitBtn = new Button("EXIT");
        TextField input = new TextField();
       VBox layout = new VBox();
        layout.getChildren().addAll(input, exitBtn);
```

However after I click the button, the window becomes empty and does not change layout.

Ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

public static variables can pass variables between classes. This is the easiest way i could think off to pull off the results you desire.

In the main class define the following variables:

```
public static Stage stage;
public static Scene sceneMain;
```

Assuming you have already set a scene and using a Stage in your main constructor write the following code after setting your Stage and Scene.

```
stage = primaryStage;
sceneMain = scene;
```

When you have done this you can easily call on to the stage in another class by and going back to your main scene like this: (this is what you can put under the event of your buttonclick())

```
Main.stage.setScene(sceneMain);
```

Or you can set another scene by simply putting the scene you want in the .setscene();